# Move elements in list

Tags: c#, .net, list, data-structures

I declare following object

```
List<string> list = {"Kate", "John", "Paul", "Eve", "Hugo"};
```

I would like to move "Eve" at front of my list? How can I do that. I must not to reorder other elements!
At output I want to get this

```
"Eve", "Kate", "John", "Paul", "Hugo"
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
list.Remove("Eve");  // Removes the first "Eve" element in the list
list.Insert(0, "Eve");  // Inserts "Eve" at the first position in the list
```

However, if your list contains multiple "Eve"s, calling Remove("Eve") will only remove the first occurrence of "Eve".

And you have to know that inserting element at the beginning of a list is an expensive operation. Because all elements already in the list have to be shifted.

#### UPDATE

As @AlvinWong commented, `LinkedList<string>` is a very good solution to avoid this overhead when inserting an element. The `Insert` operation is done in O(1) (O(n-i) in a `List`). The major drawback of `LinkedList<string>` is that accessing the `i`th element is an operation in O(i) (O(1) in a `List`).

Comment: This is a possible solution, but note that inserting an element would require moving the rest of the elements forward by one, which is quite an expensive operation.

Comment: Also if you plan on shifting the entry to a spot _later_ in the list to account for how the indices shift as well when you initially remove the entry. (might be easier to add/copy then remove in that case)

Comment: Also if you plan to frequently move elements, a `LinkedList<T>` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove and insert it to first index.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){ "Kate", "John", "Paul", "Eve", "Hugo" };
list.Remove("Eve");
list.Insert(0, "Eve");
foreach (var i in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

If you know your specific index of `"Eve"`, you can remove it with [`List.RemoveAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) method.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/eMEMit).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`List.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) (so you don't remove *all* Eve's) and [`List.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx).

Comment: `RemoveAt` is useful when you know the index of `"Eve"`. Speeds up the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoveAt method to remove Eve from the given index and use Insert to add the Eve at the start of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Remove("Eve");
list.Insert(0, "Eve");
```